# Why my Haproxy stats GUI limit sessions in backend sticks to 20000?

Tags: haproxy

My loadbalancer's GUI shows that it's backend has a `limit` of 20.000 sessions, no matter the `maxconn` parameter I set in global or in the backend sections.

[image]

When running a test, the `max` parameter in Sessions exceeds the `limit`.

Any idea how to solve it or if it's even a problem?

HAProxy version: 2.2.11-1ppa1~bionic 2021/03/18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing complex but slightly tricky, the number in the `backend` session limit is `fullconn`,

Adding `fullconn` to your backend will change that limit on the `stats` page just in case.

```
backend my-backend
        fullconn 200000
```

However, if `fullconn` is not set, it sums up all the session limit values for frontends that route to this backend, divided by 10. And there is lot more in the official documentation explained.

Reference [documentation](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.2/configuration.html#4.2-fullconn)